# Finding duration of head yaw movements from video signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to find the duration of head yaw movement. The head tracking is 
obtained  from video file that tracks head movements for each frame. 
For example, the signal plotted below has three head yaw movements. 
Is there a  way to find out the duration of signal change in the rectangles?

Yaw signal:
[image: Yaw signal]

I used SG filter and find peaks but it gives a lot of unrelated peaks as shown :

```
order =4 ;
framelen =11;
x=yaw_deg;
lx = 20;


sgf = sgolayfilt(x,order,framelen);


plot(sgf);
grid on;

hold on;
sgf=-sgf;
[pks_smoothed,locs_smoothed,widths_smoothed,proms_smoothed] = findpeaks(sgf ,'MinPeakProminence',0.009);
pks_smoothed = -pks_smoothed;
plot(locs_smoothed,pks_smoothed,'g*');
text(locs_smoothed+.02,pks_smoothed,num2str((1:numel(pks_smoothed))'));
```

[image: findpeaks]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick solution and have the **signal processing toolbox** you can use the [`findpeaks`](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) function. Playing around with various parameters should allow you to identify your peaks.

```
inv_signal = -signal;
[pks,locs,w] = findpeaks(inv_signal,'MinPeakWidth',...,'MinPeakProminence',...);
```